# why my scss doesn't working on react project on MacOS

Tags: reactjs, macos, sass, node-sass

**I have successfully installed node-sass** for my project but any change on "scss" file is not compiled.

**An example:** If i change a color on "scss" in browser i see just a color that was before on "scss" file before i have cloned the project.

> **Note:** I did it on old windows laptop and everything works fine but on mac doesn't.

**I have tried** to rebuild node-sass and reinstal node js but it deosn'work at all.

Comment: do you watch the file for any changes?
`sass --watch .../example.css : .../example.scss`
and do you use gulp or any task runners ?
did you check that you installed it globaly?

Comment: As above, please add some details about how you are running this code. What frameworks if any you are using?

Comment: i use inferno.js it is like react i run it with "npm run dev"

Comment: no i am not watch the files i will try that

Comment: i tried that with watch and it doesn't work ,like i said it works perfect on windows but on my mac it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You app i think is not watching the sass files check the `webpack.config.js` file and add this property to `module` property

```
{
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: CSSExtract.extract({
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  }
```

see if this helps

Comment: thank you but it doesn't help , i don't know why it works perfect on windows